# f:ajax doesn't work with element.click() if h:commandButton is hidden via display:none

Tags: jsf

I have input text, and if enter key is pressed on this component following js for button programmatic click is executed:

```
document.getElementById('myform:saveNew').click();
```

The button jsf:

```
<h:commandButton value="test link" action="#{myBean.save()}" style="display:none;" id="saveNew">
                <f:ajax render="interests" execute="@this"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Currently if I click enter on the input text, the whole form is submitted and reloaded. I think that AJAX is not working in this case, while if I removed `display:none;` from the button (for testing) the AJAX and rendering is working fine.

Comment: have You tried if it works with Primefaces `<p:defaultCommand>` ?

Comment: @Kuba, primefaces is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one workaround i found to hide the button and keep ajax working is to use the following class instead the style display none:

```
.hidden_button{
    height: 0px !important;
    width: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```